# Are there good habits that can mitigate conflation of list structure types in practice?

Tags: data-structures, type-systems, list

I'll start by explaining what I mean in particular.

#### Background

In Javascript, arrays do it all (more or less a Lispy trait). Not only can you initialize, push, and pop, but you can also iterate, filter, reduce, transmute, and so on. You can also check `includes` (contains), and with the overloading provided by huge libs like lodash, the sky's the limit.

The music stops when you get to a strongly typed language like Rust, where `HashSet`, `HashMap`, `Vec`, `Array`, and `Iterator` are all different beasts, each with their own capabilities and costs. You can't start with a "listy thing" and call whatever methods you realize you'll need in the moment.

#### Contrived example

Here's an example: say I have a bunch of `Foo` structs with a member `Vec` `things`. I want to get only the `Foo`s where `things` includes the specific elements I'm looking for.

In Javascript or a similar language (say, Clojure, ClojureScript), I could take an array of `Foo`s and call `.filter((foo) => foo.things.includes(target_element))`. So I get the order-preservation of `things` for `Foo` and the membership check of `things` for my target element. (Immutable.JS has `OrderedMap` even, which gilds the heck out of the lily.)

On the other hand, in Rust, I need to use a `HashMap` for `has()`, but an array or `Vec` to preserve the order of `things`.

I could mangle a function `vec_contains` that calls `filter(|this_foo| this_foo.things.as_slice().contains(target_element)).collect().len() > 0` on `things` in Rust, but now I've got a linear search and an array popping out. It feels like I'm fighting the type system.

#### Question

How do you stay out of trouble when using strongly specialized collection types in a language?

Comment: Just to make this clear, your intention is not a comparison of JavaScript vs Rust, but instead the higher level issues of statically-typed vs dynamically-typed languages with a particular interest on the liberties you can take with collection manipulation. Am I getting this correctly?

Comment: @edalorzo That's right. The Rust example "isn't that bad", but I couldn't think of a better one at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

> How do you stay out of trouble when using strongly specialized collection types in a language?

**You learn.**

JavaScript arrays may do it all, but it doesn't do it efficiently. As soon as you get into vaguely non-trivially sized collections, that linear search for `contains` isn't going to cut it. JavaScript lets you do that because it was written in a week and nobody thought it'd be used for anything serious.

You *could* do hoop jumping in the statically typed language, but the type system is there for a reason. If you find yourself jumping through hoops, you're probably doing something wrong, and it's going to hit you hard once you get more than a few dozen elements in your collections.

So you need to learn the trade offs of your collections, and design your programs to take advantage of them - even in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, could you be more concrete? I don't mean to project, but your answer seems directed at JS programmers with limited experience, or limited knowledge of data structures or computational complexity. The question also asks "Are there good habits...?"

Comment: @bright-star: Not really. I don't know Rust at all and only know a little JavaScript so I'd be hesitant to provide a concrete example that matched your problem. I use C# primarily, so there's only a few specialized collections worth knowing (`HashSet`, `ConcurrentDictionary`, and `ConcurrentQueue`), and their usage is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question leads to very opinionated answers. So, the following is just my opinion on this matter. I reckon there won't be a "right" answer for this.

You have said that this is not about JavaScript vs Rust, but in general about how you feel certain type of limitation when moving away from a dynamically-typed language like JavaScript and having to express the same ideas in statically-typed language like Rust, particularly your use of collections.

I believe that there is a mistake in your assessment, in that you think that this is a limitation that you feel due to the static nature of the language. I doubt that is the case.

Many statically-typed languages can be quite expressive particularly in their collections libraries. Just to mention a few examples, any .Net statically-typed language with LINQ, Java 8 Stream API, Scala's functional APIs and practically any statically-typed functional language offers tons of expressiveness in their collection libraries (SLM, OCaml, F#, Haskel, etc).  I daresay, in some cases, even more elegantly than JavaScript.

I don't know Rust, since it is a pretty new language, maybe the limitation that you feel is more related to a lack of expressiveness in their still immature collections API than it is the result of their static-typedness.

That example you mentioned of handling `Foos` with `things` in them, in my personal opinion and experience, could be trivially implemented in any of these statically-typed languages you speak of without any evident limitation in expressiveness. Some would look quite similar to what you'd do in JavaScript:

```
Stream.of(haystackOfFoos)
   .filter(foo -> foo.things.contains(needle))
   .map(foo -> foo.bar())
   .forEach(bar -> println(bar.name));
```

That makes me theorize: could it be the case that perhaps you are too used to working with dynamically-type languages, particularly Javascript, and now that you try with statically-typed languages it feels unfamiliar and too restrictive? If that's the case, I think that with a bit of practice and more exposure to them you will gradually cross the chasm and start appreciating them more and eventually reach more ability to express the same ideas in them.

Dynamically-typed languages are very liberal in what you can do with data structures and I find that to be pretty powerful, particularly when you come from statically-typed languages in which you're "forced" to define your abstractions more rigorously. But when you move in the opposite direction, I reckon that must be harder, because you get the feeling the the type system is somehow getting in your way to express your ideas. With practice and time, and as you get more familiarity with the language, and particularly if you define good data structures and abstractions for the domain of your problem, I think the feeling fades away and you start appreciating the powerful features of statically-typed languages more and more as you find ways to be equally expressive in them.

I doubt that I have in any way answered your question, but I hope to at least have contributed to the discussion somehow.